# HTML & CSS Simple Crossword

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design my own website, and I wanted to do a simple crossword puzzle to demonstrate some things about me. Like, every line is a diferrent word, but then there is the "middle" column that spells out another word. Here is an image of basically of what I want to do:
[image: Crossword]

The words are pre-defined by me. 
I would like to know the simplest way to do this using only HTML and CSS. I've thinked of using a table, but to make each line shift according to the word, each line would have to be a different table. 
I'm not using an image and then putting it on the site, because I want it so everytime the user hovers each word, it shows it's meaning/description on the right/left.
I'm open to using Bootstrap if it helps in anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: table would work just fine with appropriate css styling. once you have something, share the code in case of further questions, others will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since when do we use tables for layout? Just add 5 divs with a margin-left applied to them and style the `nth-child`. That way you could even add animation to it if you like.

Comment: So just to clear it up. Inside each `div`, I wrap each letter in a `span`, and then using `nth-child(1n)` on the div, I add the border?

Comment: that way you can make it responsive as well if you need it to be. With a table that becomes more cumbersome.

Comment: Not working with nth-child, not sure why. Instead I simple used `.line span{}` And since I'm not able to put a width on a `span`, I'm going to have to use `p` or something to put every square with a fixed width and height.

Comment: you can add display: inline-block to the span then you can set width

Answer (score 3):

I think that a table is actually your best bet and that you just need to add extra `<td>` tags for each empty square. You can make each square the same width by adding `td {width: 40px}` to the css.

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.letterData {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="letterData">O</td>
    <td class="letterData">N</td>
    <td class="letterData">E</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="letterData">T</td>
    <td class="letterData">W</td>
    <td class="letterData">O</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  
  <tr>
    <td class="letterData">F</td>
    <td class="letterData">O</td>
    <td class="letterData">U</td>
    <td class="letterData">R</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="letterData">T</td>
    <td class="letterData">H</td>
    <td class="letterData">R</td>
    <td class="letterData">E</td>
    <td class="letterData">E</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="letterData">E</td>
    <td class="letterData">I</td>
    <td class="letterData">G</td>
    <td class="letterData">H</td>
    <td class="letterData">T</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but it needs really a lot of styling to remove the "extra" borders. I was kind of hoping(being the key word) that there would be a more simple solution.

Comment: If you don't want the borders around everything, you can style the individual '<td>' elements that you want to have the border. Just create a class called letterData to the boxes with letters and add "letterData {border: 1px solid #000}" to the css. I will update my post.

Comment: It would probably be easier than relative positioning everything.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I can just put the base border at 0 and add the class with a border to only the letters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way would be to first define a container that represents a square:

```
.square {
    position: absolute;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

You can then position each of these thus:

```
<div id="square-0" class="square" style="top: 32px; left: 32px;">
    A
<div>
<div id="square-1" class="square" style="top: 32px; left: 64px;">
    B
</div>
<div id="square-2" class="square" style="top: 64px; left: 64px;">
    C
</div>
```

So long as you position them using top and left values that are exact multiples of the respective height and widths of your div, it should all fit together quite well.

Just an idea but that's how I'd probably do it. Give them sequential id's like square-0 and square-1 and it'll be easier to work with if you decide to expand on it programmatically in future.

Comment: I think that it would be much easier to just make a table.

Comment: It might be, depends on your needs. I'm thinking more of what I could potentially do with it using javascript/jquery, there are plenty of ways it could be done.